# How to install rsync 3.2.7 on Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I want to isntall rsync 3.2.7 on Ubuntu 20.04 - however I'm not sure if that's possible; currently I have 3.1.3 installed on the system (which is installed by default).

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389729/install-latest-version-of-rsync-3-2-3-on-ubuntu-18-04) but it only mentions 3.2.3 which doesn't interest me.

Trying to install 3.2.7 from deb package intended for 22.04 obviously failed

After ~1h or researching I couldn't find any way nor information that would point me to the solution on how to install 3.2.7 or if that's even possible.

Comment: Why do you want this specific version in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do:

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list` (backup it before).

Substitute all occurrences of `fridge` to `jammy`.

Then run

```
apt update
```

```
$ apt policy rsync
rsync:
  Installed: 3.2.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
  Candidate: 3.2.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.2.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.2.3-8ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

```
apt upgrade rsync
```

**Then if `apt` is not trying to upgrade the whole system, should be a `go`.**

After this, restore backup file(s), then run again `apt update`.

Or maybe consider upgrading to `jammy`.

Comment: It's kind of a tricky/risk solution and I had some errors during rsync installation however for my testing purposes it worked and rsync 3.2.7 was installed - thanks a lot !

Comment: For LinuxMint, that's the way to upgrade between versions without reinstalling via cd-rom or USB stick. I use it also for major Debian releases to upgrade the whole system

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add a repo and install it from there but the issue is that the repos are created for later releases of Ubuntu such as 22.04 and 22.10. Most of time time, you'll be okay but it's the one time where it installs or updates packages that aren't in line with what is supported by the repos for your release and you end up in dependency hell.

The best option is to compile it from source.

The source code for `rsync 3.2.7` is here: https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/releases/tag/v3.2.7

You will need to make sure that build essential is installed for the compiler tools. Afterwards, prepend the directory of the `rsync 3.2.7` binary to your `$PATH` via one of your shell init files so that it is there at login and then source it or start a new shell session or use `export PATH=/path/to/rsync/bi/:$PATH` for it to take effect immediately. This will give you what you need while avoiding dependency hell by adding a repo with later packages.